# Android: NinePatch and LayerList

Tags: android, overlay, nine-patch

So I'm trying to overlay a map image with a transparent ninepatch Drawable using layer-list. Like this:

[target http://f.cl.ly/items/2b1x3c3o0w3t1z0b2o2s/Screen%20Shot%202012-06-20%20at%2010.34.18%20AM.png](http://f.cl.ly/items/2b1x3c3o0w3t1z0b2o2s/Screen%20Shot%202012-06-20%20at%2010.34.18%20AM.png)

But all I get is this (notice that the map image is cropped by the edges of the ninepatch, even though it is supposed to be transparent):

[problem http://f.cl.ly/items/380j3E2w452Y2D2d1K0a/Screen%20Shot%202012-06-20%20at%2010.29.45%20AM.png](http://f.cl.ly/items/380j3E2w452Y2D2d1K0a/Screen%20Shot%202012-06-20%20at%2010.29.45%20AM.png)

Here's my layer-list code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
      <nine-patch android:src="@drawable/myninepatch" />
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/detail_map"/>
  </layer-list>
```

and here's my layout ImageView:

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="298dp"
        android:layout_height="106dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:src="@drawable/detail_map_overlay" />
```

**Edit:** Here's the ninepatch .png:

[ninepatch http://f.cl.ly/items/0X3N0d331Q15380D093n/myninepatch.9.png](http://f.cl.ly/items/0X3N0d331Q15380D093n/myninepatch.9.png)

Any ideas how to achieve this? Not necessarily using ninepatch but I want to make it stretchable depending on the size of the image. Or if you have an idea how to do inner glow, that would be swell too.

Comment: could you provide your 9-patch (or a zoom of it) in your question to see if there is a problem with it?

Comment: surely, I'll add it to the post, thanks!

Comment: don't you forget the bottom and right black bar for the padding?

Comment: that doesn't need to be there, does it? I changed it but it didn't help.

Comment: the top and left part only define the stretchable area, the bottom and right, the position of the content. You must set the content to the edge of your shape.

Comment: oh ok, that solved it, also the order in the layer-list was wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*To recap the comments and make it more clear for further reading*

You 9 patch is not valid:

- the top and left part only define the stretchable area.
- the bottom and right, the position of the content.

With your example, it will do something like this(based on your but without the useless parts):

[image: 9 patch corrected]

Then set it as background of your ImageView:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="298dp"
    android:layout_height="106dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
    android:src="@drawable/detail_map"
    android:background="@drawable/myninepatch">
</ImageView>
```

Like this you can get rid of the Layer List

Comment: the map should be the background and the ninepatch the src though, right?

Comment: a 9-patch as src does not work. It need to be as background. It will be a problem for the transparency at the edge of the 9 patch.
Keep the LayerList...